# Passing data between sibling components in Svelte

Tags: svelte, svelte-component, svelte-store, routify

How to pass data (ex: Navbar Title) to a component used in the parent element?

```
<!-- _layout.svelte -->
<script>
  import Nav from "../components/Nav.svelte";
  let navTitle = "MyApp";
</script>

<Nav {navTitle}/>
<slot />
```

```
<!-- Nav.svelte -->
<script>
  export let navTitle = "";
</script>
<h1>{navTitle}</h1>
```

```
<!-- Login.svelte -->
How to pass navTitle value from here to Nav.svelte?
```

To clarify, this needs to be scalable and to work on page load/transition for all routes of an SPA using Routify, preferably providing a default value and be able to have HTML value:

```
<!-- Article.svelte -->
```

```
<!-- User.svelte -->
navTitle is '<a href="/user">My Account </a>'
```

```
<!-- Comment.svelte -->
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The easiest way to share data across components is to use stores as described in the [docs](https://svelte.dev/docs#svelte_store)

Your setup for that would be

```html
<!-- Nav.svelte -->
<script>
  import { navTitle } from './store.js'
</script>
<h1>{$navTitle}</h1>
```

```html
<!-- Login.svelte -->
<script>
  import { navTitle } from './store.js'

  navTitle.set('...')
</script>
```

```js
<!-- store.js -->
import { writable } from 'svelte/store'

export const navTitle = writable('')
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, @stephane. I updated the question to clarify scalability and default values issues. Would you make any updates to your suggestion? For example, Routify allows to set metatag.title on pages by simply using  `$: metatags.title = "Log in";`

Comment: You can import _navTitle_ wherever in your app you want to be able to set it and then set it similar to how you set it in Routify

Comment: $navTitle seems to be escaping HTML and only showing text. Is there a way to pass HTML to it?

Comment: Svelte automatically escapes texts, if you want to override this you can use `{@html $navTitle}` but when doing that you have to make sure it is always safe to do so (outputting unescaped html can be a source for XSS)

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a function to `Login.svelte` component

```
<script>
  import Nav from "./Nav.svelte";
  import Login from "./Login.svelte"
  let navTitle = "MyApp";
  const onlogin= (v)=>navTitle = v
</script>
<Login {onlogin}/>
<Nav {navTitle}/>
```

And call the passed function in the `Login.svelte`

```
<script>
export let onlogin
</script>

<p on:click={()=>onlogin("Logged in")}>
  click me to login
</p>
```

Here is the REPL: https://svelte.dev/repl/f1c8777df93f414ab26734013f2c4789?version=3

There are other (better) ways to do this like:

- Custom events with `createEventDispatcher`
- Stores
- Context (`setContext`, `getContext`)
- Multiple Redux-adaptations for svelte

Comment: You can use also two-way binding for this, but it should be avoided (you’ll mess your dataflow pretty quickly). In App.svelte `<Login bind:navTitle/>` and in Login.svelte `export let navTitle` and `<p on:click={()=>navTitle=("Logged in")}>` Key-word is `bind:`, which makes two-way binding to `navTitle` variable ie. when variable changes in one place, it’ll change also other places.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this example](https://svelte.dev/repl/e7719405bd04453aa535d898716c5c90?version=3.35.0) in case you need to communicate between sibling elements but you need the shared data to be specific to each group of sibling components.